# How to join tables in laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

In my case, I have 3 tables like Question, options, and answers

Questions table

```
|id      |     question_name|
------------------------------
      1          question1
      2          question2 
      3          question3
```

options table

```
id  |     question_id     |   options |
----------------------------------------
1           1                   option1
----------------------------------------
1           1                   option2
----------------------------------------
1           1                   option3
----------------------------------------
1           1                   option4
```

Answers table

```
id   |   customer_id |   question_id | answer(selected by user) |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
 1               1              1               option1          
--------------------------------------------------------------------
 1               2              2               option2            
--------------------------------------------------------------------
 1               1              3               option3    
--------------------------------------------------------------------
 1               1              3               option2
```

How can I get below output from answers using joins table
      For customer 1

```
 question1
    --option1
 question2
    --option2
 question3
    --option3
    --option2
```

I have eloquent relation,

```
 Question model 
    class Question extends Model
    {
        public function options()
        {
            return $this->hasMany(Option::class);
        }
        public function customer()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo(CustomerProfile::class);
        }
        public function answers()
       {
            return $this->hasMany(Answer::class);
       }
    }

  Option model
      public function question()
      {
        return $this->belongsTo(Question::class);
      }

   Answer model 
      public function customer()
      {
          return $this->belongsTo(CustomerProfile::class);
      }
      public function question()
      {
          return $this->belongsTo(Question::class);
      }
```

That is how my relationships looks like, Now I just need to join the tables to get output.

Comment: What is the eloquent relation? Can you please post your code.

Comment: Have you read the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships)?

Comment: @fubar yes I have read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going off the comment you left on Aaron Fahey's answer, you'll need to add a constraint to the query and the eager-load:

```
$customerId = 1; 

$questions = Question::with([
    'options', 'answers' => function ($query) use ($customerId) {
        $query->where('customer_id', $customerId);
    }])
    ->whereHas('answers', function ($query) use ($customerId) {
        $query->where('customer_id', $customerId);
    })
    ->get();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the related options for your questions, you can use [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading).

An example would be:

```
$questions = Question::with('options')->get();
```

You will then have a collection with the questions, and their related options. You will need to construct a loop to get the data you want.

Comment: Actually I need to get data from answers table according to customer id,output should be  question1
    --option1
 question2
    --option2
 question3
    --option3
    --option2

Comment: `Question::with('answers')->get();` should be want you want then

Comment: what I want is customer has answered 3 question and that data available in answers table, Now I need to grab that data from answers table, If I say customer id 1 it should show all the questions with an answer that customer 1 has answered.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you also have defined eloquent relations in Customer Model class.
If you do so, then you can retrieve all the answers of a particular customer through customer model and this will give you the hook to get the answer's question and its all options:

```
$customer = Customer::find($customerId);
$answer = $customer->answers()->where('id', $answerId)->get();

$question = $answer->question;

$questionOptions = $question->options;
```

I hope it will help.

Comment: Hello @asmmahmud Thank you for your answer, but what is that variable  $answerId,

Comment: If you want to find a specific answer for a specific customer then you can use the $answerid. but, you can use it other way : $allAnswers = $customer->answers; . This will give you all the answers for a specific customer.